# Where are the text/audio-logs located?

Tags: the-talos-principle

Where are all the text/audio-logs located?

If there's a puzzle related to finding it, just the general location is fine - no puzzle-spoilers :)

Comment: You mean terminals and audio logs of Alexandra? (there like every where, *mostly* in an open space - you don't need to look them). Or something else?

Comment: @klm123 Well, just because they're in open space, doesn't mean they're not hard to find. There's one world where I can here the terminal, but I can't find it. Also, they sometimes put them in unexpected places, like behind building #3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list adapted from [a trophy guide by littlelostkiwi](https://psnprofiles.com/guide/3517-the-talos-principle-trophy-guide).  There are additional details in that guide if you need them.

### Time Capsules

These generally aren't hard to find if you just run around the area and look behind walls.

- Time Capsule 01 - A-2
- Time Capsule 02 - A-4
- Time Capsule 03 - A-5
- Time Capsule 04 - A-7
- Time Capsule 05 - B-2
- Time Capsule 06 - B-4
- Time Capsule 07 - B-7
- Time Capsule 08 - B-7
- Time Capsule 09 - C-1
- Time Capsule 10 - C-3
- Time Capsule 11 - C-5
- Time Capsule 12 - C-6
- Time Capsule 13 - C-7
- Time Capsule 14 - C-7
- Time Capsule 15 - World C Messenger Island
- Time Capsule 16 - World A Messenger Island
- Time Capsule 17 - World B Messenger Island
- Time Capsule 18 - 1st Floor of the Tower
- Time Capsule 19 - 2nd Floor of the Tower
- Time Capsule 20 - 3rd Floor of the Tower
- Time Capsule 21 - 4th Floor of the Tower
- Time Capsule 22 - 5th Floor of the Tower

### Computer Terminals

The main terminals will be hard to miss.  The extra ones usually aren't hard to find if you run around and listen for the beeps.

- Terminal A01
- Terminal A02
- Terminal A02 Extra
- Terminal A03
- Terminal A04
- Terminal A05
- Terminal A06
- Terminal A06 Extra
- Terminal A06 Extra 2

  > Behind the wall between the puzzles "Mobile Minefield" and "Deception".  You'll hear it beeping when you're near the wall. There's a Hexahedron in the far right corner (relative to where you teleported in) you can use to climb over. There's a ladder to let you out again.
- Terminal A07
- Terminal A08 - In the extra level behind the World A star gate
- Terminal B01
- Terminal B01 Extra
- Terminal B02
- Terminal B03
- Terminal B03 Extra
- Terminal B04
- Terminal B05
- Terminal B05 Extra
- Terminal B06
- Terminal B07
- Terminal B07 Extra
- Terminal B08 - In the extra level behind the World B star gate
- Terminal C01
- Terminal C01 Extra

  > On the right side of the map on the teleporter side of the bridge
- Terminal C02
- Terminal C03
- Terminal C04
- Terminal C05
- Terminal C05 Extra
- Terminal C06
- Terminal C07
- Terminal C08 - In the extra level behind the World C star gate
- Land A Elevator
- Land B Elevator
- Land C Elevator
- Land C Elevator Hidden

  > Outside the building under the rear overhang.
- Tower Floor 1
- Tower Floor 2
- Tower Floor 3
- Tower Floor 4